# Table Mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I was playing around with tables and having text change as you mouse over each table. This code I have now works to change the first table's text but I am not sure how to get it to work for the other tables as well...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function highlight(id) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "SF";
    }

    function unhighlight(id) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Giants";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.write('<table width="300" id="i" onmouseover="highlight(i);" onmouseout="unhighlight(i);">');
        document.write('<tr>');
        document.write('<td id="name">Giants</td>');
        document.write('<td>5</td>');
        document.write('</tr>');
        document.write('</table>');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `id` name is repeated in all the tables. so `document.getElementById("name")` will always find the first element with id `name`. You have to make it unique in each table then it should work fine. Also you have to pass something to `highlight` method to identify the mouse over/out table.

```js
 function highlight(id) {
   document.getElementById("name" + id).innerHTML = "SF";
 }

 function unhighlight(id) {
   document.getElementById("name" + id).innerHTML = "Giants";
 }

 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   document.write('<table width="300" id="i" onmouseover="highlight(' + i + ');" onmouseout="unhighlight(' + i + ');">');
   document.write('<tr>');
   document.write('<td id="name' + i + '">Giants</td>');
   document.write('<td>5</td>');
   document.write('</tr>');
   document.write('</table>');
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great... Still learning about all this javascript stuff so I always miss weird things like this